# PHP & Javascript Search in a dropdown select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a select with many rows (100/200++) and it's very hard to select something because are to many and it's take to long to find what you want.
So i want to make a new input and when value it's change in dropdown select need to remains only rows which contains that value from input.
Does anybody know how i can make or have something like that?
Thanks!

Comment: Google for `chosen`(https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) or `select2` (https://select2.github.io/)...

Comment: here is [link](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

Comment: I will recommend you to go for select2 because there are few drawbacks using chosen. Here is the link : https://select2.github.io/

Comment: Chosen is disabled on iPhone, iPod Touch, and Android mobile devices. Check it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22016578/chosen-plugin-doesnt-seem-to-work-on-mobile-browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try chosen

https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

You can search select just like a search form.

Its too simple to implement.

```
$(function(){
  $(element).chosen();
});
```

**Note:** Chosen is not supported on android or IOS, "Chosen is disabled on iPhone, iPod Touch, and Android mobile devices "

Comment: Chosen is disabled on iPhone, iPod Touch, and Android mobile devices. Check it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22016578/chosen-plugin-doesnt-seem-to-work-on-mobile-browsers

Comment: It's okay for my request, i only need for desktop browsers, so it's perfect! Thanks.

Comment: @VladutZzZ Then this is perfect for you :)

Comment: @VladutZzZ, thanks, if my answer works for you, please accept it as solution so that other uses can gain.